# How to pass multiple string parameter to the function in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to pass multiple string as parameter to the function

**Function**:

```
void addColumn(java.lang.String... headers)
```

**Description**

Add a row of column headers to this grid.
This should be called once per dimension on the column, and the length of headers from each dimension should match.

Example call from Groovy that adds Jan, Feb, Mar from FY16 and FY17:

```
builder.addColumn('2016', '2016', '2016', '2017', '2017', '2017') 
builder.addColumn('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar')
```

So If I pass the parameter like in the above example it works fine.. I couldn't figure out the way to pass it dynamically in groovy??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always pass an array of Strings in this case. Your method

```
void addColumn(java.lang.String... headers)
```

uses [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) and it means that you can call this method as it was

```
void addColumn(java.lang.String[] headers)
```

Varargs is useful in some cases, because it accepts single parameter as well as n-number of parameters with the same type.

If you want to call this method in Groovy you can do it by passing a list cast to `String[]`, e.g.

```
def addColumn(String... args) {
    args.each { println "Adding column ${it}..."}
}

println 'Ex 1:'
addColumn('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr')

println 'Ex 2:'
addColumn(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'] as String[])
```

Running this script will print to the output:

```
Ex 1:
Adding column Jan...
Adding column Feb...
Adding column Mar...
Adding column Apr...
Ex 2:
Adding column Jan...
Adding column Feb...
Adding column Mar...
Adding column Apr...
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the splat operator:

```
def headers = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']

addColumn(*headers)
```

which will unroll the collection as varags in this case.

Comment: Thanks for response.. I tried the code but it gave me this error..[Static type checking] - The spread operator cannot be used as argument of method or closure calls with static type checking because the number of arguments cannot be determined at compile time

Comment: Are you using `@CompileStatic` on your code? If so, it won't work with that you'd need to remove the annotation. If you can't remove it, then I am not sure how to do what you ask.

Comment: You could also mark the specific method that this code is in with the SKIP version of the annotation to make it non-static.

Comment: I am not aware of @compilestatic. This function is provided by the Oracle tool and we are just calling this function. As I mention if I hardcode addColumn(Jan,Feb) it works but I want to pass the parameters dynamically.. not sure how to get this work :(

Comment: If this tool is forcing static compilation, then not sure what you can do.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. so I may have to hardcode the parameters... which would be really difficult..